# Argo Workflows semaphore with value 0

Tags: kubernetes, semaphore, argo-workflows, argoproj

I'm learning about semaphores in the Argo project workflows to avoid concurrent workflows using the same resource.

My use case is that I have several external resources which only one workflow can use one at a time. So far so good, but sometimes the resource needs some maintenance and during that period I don't want to Argo to start any workflow.

I guess I have two options:

- I tested manually setting the semaphore value in the configMap to the value 0, but Argo started one workflow anyway.
- I can start a workflow that runs forever, until it is deleted, claiming the synchronization lock, but that requires some extra overhead to have workflows running that don't do anything.

So I wonder how it is supposed to work if I set the semaphore value to 0, I think it should not start the workflow then since it says 0. Anyone have any info about this?

This is the steps I carried out:

1. First I apply my configmap with kubectl -f.
2. I then submit some workflows and since they all use the same semaphore Argo will start one and the rest will be executed in order one at a time.
3. I then change value of the semapore with kubectl edit configMap
4. Submit new job which then Argo will execute.

Perhaps Argo will not reload the configMap when I update the configMap through kubectl edit? I would like to update the configmap programatically in the future but used kubectl edit now for testing.

Comment: Can you post the exact reproduction steps? I just tested a semaphore with value `0`, and it behaved as expected (blocked workflow execution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix: after applying the ConfigMap change, cycle the workflow-controller pod. That will force it to reload semaphore state.

I couldn't reproduce your exact issue. After using `kubectl edit` to set the semaphore to `0`, any newly submitted workflows remained `Pending`.

I *did* encounter an issue where using `kubectl edit` to bump up the semaphore limit did not automatically kick off any of the `Pending` workflows. Cycling the workflow controller pod allowed the workflows to start running again.

Besides using the quick fix, I'd recommend submitting an [issue](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/issues). Synchronization is a newer feature, and it's possible it's not 100% robust yet.

Comment: Ok, I did encounter the same issue you got after  cycling the workflow manager. Thank you for your quick help and I will submit an issue on their github page.